# Hide Keyboard in iOS7 with DatePicker as Keyboard

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, uikeyboard

Currently, I am able to have my keyboard appear when I use a text field in my form. However, I'm not able to hide it. So I always need to shutdown the app and to open it back to change pages. I know there is a way to have like a toolbar to close the Keyboard when you want. However, i don't manage to see how to have this toolbar appear.

However, one of my fields enable a DatePicker View as a Keyboard instead of the natural keyboard.

```
- (void) initializeTextFieldInputView {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.minuteInterval = 5;
    datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateUpdated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.DateText.inputView = datePicker;
}

- (void) dateUpdated:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    self.DateText.text = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
}
```

Comment: Please note that currently, none of my fields have the ability to make the keyboard disapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide a keyboard either `[self.DateText resignFirstResponder]` or `[self.view endEditing:YES]` would work.

To add a toolbar over the keyboard use `[self.DateText setInputAccessoryView:yourToolBarView];`